# How to express " I lost my senses/reasoning/brain when my wife fights with me"

Tags: word-choice

I have a question in this sentence " I lost my senses/reasoning/brain/mind when my wife fights with me". I want to say that when fighting with my wife, sometimes I am  crazy and lose my "mind". I want to ask what's the appropriate word for "mind"? I have some potential candidate words such as "senses/reasoning/brain/mind" but I am not sure what fits best. Please help~~

Comment: 1. You would make the tense of 'lose' and 'fight' the same, e.g. lose/fights. 2. Have you thought of getting help with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To "lose your mind" is a common expression that means to go crazy, usually temporarily.

It fits very well in the context of fighting with your wife because you calm down after and stop being crazy.

Comment: Yes, but, as Michael says, if it happens repeatedly you say 'I lose my mind', not 'lost'.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, Gotube and Kate. I appreciate your help~~ : )